# The Filter of my Java- Stream does not work

Tags: java, list, stream, hashmap, java-stream

I can´t explain why my filter does not work. I exclude the condition in an `if`-statement to check that the condition is really true and it is. I don´t want to have the value in my `List` when the `DefaultLang` (`v.getLinkDefaultLang()`) and the currentLang (`v.getLinkCurrentLang()`) are Null!

```java
manualResponseTOs.values().stream()
                          .filter(v -> isEmpty(v.getLinkDefaultLang()) && isEmpty(v.getLinkCurrentLang()))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You need to reverse the condition, if isEmpty return true for null, since filter use to filter out which are valid for collect

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! Now I have the solution.

```
filter(v-> !(isEmpty(v.getLinkDefaultLang()) && isEmpty(v.getLinkCurrentLang())))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter per condition as opposed to having all conditions on the same line if you like. It's a bit more readable.

```java
manualResponseTOs.values().stream()
        .filter(v -> !isEmpty(v.getLinkDefaultLang()))
        .filter(v -> !isEmpty(v.getLinkCurrentLang()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```